# Godot add optional left padding to VBox control node?

Tags: godot

How can I add optional padding to a VBox control node without having the padding expand the minimum space the entire VBox node takes up?

For example, the layout should normally look like this:

```
| padding | VBox content |
```

But when there's not enough space, the padding can shrink

```
| padd | VBox content |
```

All the way down to 0

```
|| VBox content |
```

I tried using a margin container, but the margin will not shrink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
VBox
'-HBox
  '-Optional padding left
  '-VBox
    '-Content
    '-Content
    '-Content
```

I did

```
VBox
'-VBox
  '-HBox
    '-Optional padding left
    '-Content
  '-HBox
    '-Optional padding left
    '-Content
```

The RectMinSize on the padding is set to 0 horizontally, so the padding can shrink all the way down to nothing. I then set the horizontal size flags of each content and padding to `SizeFlags.ExpandFill`, and I have the `SizeFlagsStretchRatio` of the padding set to `0.1`, and for the content, it's set to `1`. This way, the padding will normally take up a small, fixed % of the space but can still shrink down to 0.

However, I still haven't found a way to make fixed-length padding shrinkable. But for now, I'm happy with using ratio-based shrinkable padding.